# Convert Tensorflow 1.0 code into 2.0 version

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am facing issue while converting my tensorflow 1.0 code into 2.0

I can convert successful this

version 1

```
 # reset underlying graph data
 #tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Version 2

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
ops.reset_default_graph()
```

This is the code below which i am having issue please help me out how can i build NN in tensorflow 2 version

```
# Build neural network
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)
# Define model and setup tensorboard
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')
# Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)
model.fit(train_x, train_y, n_epoch=100, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
model.save('my_drive/AI_values/model/model.ckpt')
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I could not understand your question properly (i.e what is version 1 and version 2 and what do you want to convert from tf 1.0 to tf 2.0) but to convert any code from tensorflow version 1.0 to 2.0 is very easy.

While importing tensorflow instead of doing `import tensorflow as tf` do `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf` and if you want to import a specific module from tensorflow(e.g `from tensorflow.keras.models import Model`) do `from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.models import Model`.

Comment: Thanks for reply ! I want to convert from version 1 to version 2 means need to upgrade my code  you told that is easy but i tried but not working can you convert above code if possible.

Answer (score 3):

tf_upgrade_v2 — infile foo.py — outfile foo-upgraded.py

this command can easily convert your tensorflow code from 1.0 to 2.0 for full thing you can refer (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmSNUeBG-PQ)